# How to restore image color after converting it from a float32 type to uint8 type in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So I am trying to detect an aruco marker in an image and the function requires the image to be of uint8 type, so I converted the image using this formula:

`IMG = ((img.astype(np.uint8)*255)) #img is the original float32 type image`

Here is the image as float32 type:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfr3V.jpg)

Converted it into uint8 type, then passed it to a function **which required a uint8 type image to work with** then I got this: [Image uint8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VftZ4.png)

The function to which I passed the Image is:

```
def detect_Aruco(img):  #returns the detected aruco list dictionary with id: corners
    aruco_list = {}
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_5X5_50)
    parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    #lists of ids and the corners belonging to each id
    corners, ids, _ = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters = parameters)
    # print len(corners), corners, ids
    gray = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(gray, corners,ids)
    # cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    #print (type(corners[0]))
    if len(corners):    #returns no of arucos
        #print (len(corners))
        #print (len(ids))
        for k in range(len(corners)):
            temp_1 = corners[k]
            temp_1 = temp_1[0]
            temp_2 = ids[k]
            temp_2 = temp_2[0]
            aruco_list[temp_2] = temp_1
        return aruco_list
```

TLDR; I want to get the Image2 but with original color that it had. Any help?

EDIT: This is my original image array(in float32): [Image as float array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzXoC.png)

EDIT 2: I think I got it. 
For increasing the contrast I multiplied it by 3. The values went >1. So the normalization was wrong.

Also as the comment suggested, correct line was: `ENHAN_IMG = ((enhan_img*255).astype(np.uint8))`

Comment: Multiply by 255 first, then cast to uint8.

Comment: It gives a desaturated image, blue becomes yellow, purple becomes green, inversion